# How can I map values out of an onClick event into an action in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am experimenting with an Elm app in which I wish to generate actions from clicking within a div, but I wish the actions to contain the coordinates of the click.

I can see that I can generate actions from clicks like this:

```
div [onClick address MyAction] [text "click in here"]
```

But I can't see how to apply a mapping function to the original click data to populate fields in MyAction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull different properties out of the javascript event object using Json Decoders. To get the `clientX` and `clientY` values as a tuple, you could create the following decoder:

```elm
import Json.Decode as Json exposing ((:=))

eventPos : Json.Decoder (Int, Int)
eventPos =
  Json.object2
    (,)
    ("clientX" := Json.int)
    ("clientY" := Json.int)
```

In order to do something with those values, you'll need to add an Action that can accept the tuple as a parameter:

```elm
type Action
  = MyAction
  | DivClicked (Int, Int)
```

Finally, instead of using the `onClick` function to generate the event handler attribute on your div, you'll need to use the `on` function, passing in your Json decoder:

```elm
on "click" eventPos (Signal.message address << DivClicked)
```

Here's a gist containing a [working example](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/cf632c73bcb1a2deb3ef) that you can paste right into http://elm-lang.org/try.